# Installed ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX driver, but it is not being used by window manager. How do I enable it?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have conflicting information being given to me, on the one hand the *"Additional Drivers"* panel mentions that the **ATI/AMD** proprietary driver is installed, but the *"Details"* panel tells me the `"Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300) "` is in use.

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04 beta**

[image]

How do I make sure the **ATI** driver is used?

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "FGL.renamed.libglx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone through a program of deleting the installed fglrx drivers installed by Ubuntu, then following these steps http://ubuntuportal.com/new-ati-catalyst-12-3-has-been-released-how-to-install-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-linux-mint-12/ to install the updated AMD drivers.

This got things going for me.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the string "LoadModule" in /var/log/Xorg.0.log. You will have to repeat the search several times until you get to the one that shows your video driver. Whatever shows in this file is the one that is being used.